# Differences of datetime between windows and linux

Tags: c#

I'm using this code line

```cs
DateTime planExpDate = Convert.ToDateTime("7/14/37 8:11:02 AM");
```

to get date under windows and linux OS,

I got 7/14/2037 in windows, and 7/14/1937 in linux.

Also when I pass 7/14/20 I will got 7/14/2020 in windows and linux and I can't understand that to fix it.

Anyone has idea ?
Thanks.

Comment: try to use [DateTime.ParseExact()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: @styx - Does `ParseExact` deal with centuries differently?

Comment: @Enigmativity well it does not, but you can provide the format that you want there and the `FormatProvider` which might help him

Comment: @styx - It seems to be a default century issue.

Comment: I stepped through about 7 levels of methodsand calls and parsing/tokenizing on [c#-reference for Convert.ToDateTime](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs,3dcde4b72349960c) but I am unable to pinpoint the culprit - sorry. Interesting question though.

Comment: the range for a 2-digit year is set in in control panel > region > additional settings. Anyway it's a bad idea to parse date like that. Use locale-independent format, or that may result in different outputs in different environments